# d3 redraw bar chart with new values

Tags: d3.js

My barchart draws fine when the page first loads.

But choose hour 2 from the drop-down, and it doesn't want to update to hour 2 data, it just keeps displaying hour 1.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt0yo40/7/)

This is my d3 and js:

```
$('#bar_chart').css('overflow-x','scroll');

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 80},
    width = 220 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 233 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom');

var formatComma = d3.format('0,000');

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(5)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickFormat(formatComma);


var svg = d3.select('th.chart-here').append('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 220 233')
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin meet')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left/1.5 + ',' + margin.top/1.5 + ')');


var table_i = 0;

var arr1 =
[
{'hour':1,'car':[{'audi':1377},{'bmw':716},{'ford':3819},{'mazda':67},{'toyota':11580},{'tesla':0}]},
{'hour':2,'car':[{'audi':9000},{'bmw':2000},{'ford':7000},{'mazda':1000},{'toyota':5000},{'tesla':700}]},
];

var hour = arr1[table_i];
var car=hour.car;
    var newobj = [];
    for(var hourx1=0;hourx1<car.length;hourx1++){
    var xx = car[hourx1];
    for (var value in xx) {
    var chartvar = newobj.push({car:value,miles:xx[value]});
    var data = newobj;
    }
}

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.car; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.miles; })]);

  svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'start');

function changeHour(){  
  svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('transform','translate(-20)') //move rects closer to Y axis
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.car); })
        .attr('width', x.rangeBand()*1)
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.miles); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return height - y(d.miles); });


  xtext = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,' + height + ')') //move tick text so it aligns with rects
      .call(xAxis);
xtext.selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
return 'translate(' + this.getBBox().height*50 + ',' + this.getBBox().height + ')rotate(0)';
         });

//code to enable jqm checkbox
    $('#checkbox-2a').on('change', function(e){
    originalchange(e);
});

$( '#checkbox-2a' ).checkboxradio({
  defaults: true
});
  var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#checkbox-2a').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio( 'refresh' ).change();
  }, 1000);

function originalchange() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);
    var IsChecked = $('#checkbox-2a').is(':checked');

    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(IsChecked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.miles - a.miles; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.car, b.car); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.car; }))

        .copy();

    svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .sort(function(a, b) { return x0(a.car) - x0(b.car); });

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(950),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll('.bar')
        .delay(delay)
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x0(d.car); });

    transition.select('.x.axis')
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('g')
        .delay(delay);
  };
}
changeHour();

$('select').change(function() { //function to change hourly data
table_i = $(this).val();
var hour = arr1[table_i];
var car=hour.car;
var newobj = [];
    for(var hourx1=0;hourx1<car.length;hourx1++){
    var xx = car[hourx1];
        for (var value in xx) {
        var chartvar = newobj.push({car:value,miles:xx[value]});
        var data = newobj;
    }
}

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.car; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.miles; })]);

    changeHour();
    })
```

I thought that by updating in the function `changeHour` I could isolate just the rects and the text that goes with them, and redraw them based on the selected hour's data.

But it just keeps drawing the first hour.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things not working:

firstly "data" needs to be declared without 'var' in the change function at the end. Declaring it with 'var' makes it a local variable to that function, and once you leave that function it's gone. Saying "data = " without the var means you're using the data variable you've declared further up. It's all to do with scope which is something I still struggle with, but basically with 'var' it doesn't work.

```
var newobj = [];
    for(var hourx1=0;hourx1<car.length;hourx1++){
    var xx = car[hourx1];
        for (var value in xx) {
        var chartvar = newobj.push({car:value,miles:xx[value]});
    }
}
data = newobj;
```

Secondly, your changeHour function only looks for new elements as it hangs all its attribute settings on an .enter() selection, changeHour should be like this:

```
var dataJoin = svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.car; });

    // possible new elements, fired first time, set non-data dependent attributes
    dataJoin
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('transform','translate(-20)') //move rects closer to Y axis

    // changes to existing elements (now including the newly appended elements from above) which depend on data values (d)
    dataJoin
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.car); })
        .attr('width', x.rangeBand()*1)
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.miles); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return height - y(d.miles); });
```

For completeness there should be a `dataJoin.exit().remove()` in there as well but its not something that happens in this dataset

Comment: your changeHour rewrite works, in conjunction with your variable scope suggestion -- many thanks. Now I have to study it to see why. It looks to be a variation of the general enter-update-exit method others have described (which I find difficult to grasp).